# sed: replace a pattern between two similar patterns, i.e. ( replace " to ' between two "," )

Tags: sed

I have a csv file whose fields are delimited by double quote (") and comma (,), e.g:

```
"123","4"5""6","789"
```

However, there may be some double quote (") within the data, i.e. `4"5""6` which I need to transform into single quote ('), i.e.

I need to transform

```
"123","4"5""6","789"
```

to

```
"123","4'5''6","789"
```

I've tried something like

```
sed "s/\(\",\"\)\(\"\|[^\(","\)]\)*\(\",\"\)/\1'\3/"g
```

but `(\"\|[^\(","\)]\)*` only

match `"` OR not `","`

but may be I need something like

match `"` AND not `","`

---

Another approach may be perform sequential sed, i.e.

1. find and match 4"5""6 first
2. pass the result to next statement and replace to 4'5' '6

But for both ways, I don't know exactly how to do it.

---

Although I can replace all `"` into `'` first and then re-format my csv but it seems to be costly, i.e.
`sed -i -e "s/\"/'/g" -e "s/','/\",\"/g" -e "s/^'/\"/g" -e "s/'$/\"/g" myFile.csv`

Comment: what's your operation system?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It's CentOS 7.3

Comment: can you admit a "non-sed"(other one-liner) solution?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Of course!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ sed ':a;s/\("[^,"]*\)"\([^,].*\)/\1'\''\2/;ta' <<< '"1"23","4"5""6","78"9"'
"1'23","4'5''6","78'9"
```

Opening double quote and following characters up to(but excluding) next closing `"` are captured and replaced with captured string and one single quote.

If replacement succeeds,  `ta` loops to the beginning of the script for further replacements.

Answer (score 0):

> find and match 4"5""6 first
>
> pass the result to next statement and replace to 4'5' '6

This is possible in `perl`

```
$ echo '"123","4"5""6","789"' | perl -pe 's/"\K[^,]+(?=")/$&=~s|"|\x27|gr/ge'
"123","4'5''6","789"
```

- `"\K[^,]+(?=")` match column content, leave out outer double quotes with use of lookarounds
- `$&=~s|"|\x27|gr` replace the double quotes found within column content with single quotes

  - The `e` modifier used allows this usage of Perl code instead of replacement string

Workaround with `sed`, involves messy branches

```
$ echo '"123","4"5""6","789"' | sed -E ':a s/("[^,]+)"([^,]+")(,|$)/\1\x27\2\3/; ta'
"123","4'5''6","789"
```

- `:a` mark label
- `("[^,]+)"([^,]+")(,|$)` matches column content with at least one inner double quote
- `\1\x27\2\3` replace the inner double quote with single quote
- `ta` branch to label `a` as long as there is a match

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '"123","4"5""6","789"'|sed -r ':a;s/^([^,]+,"[^,]*)"([^"]*",)/\1\x27\2/;ta'
```

Comment: please add explanation and this won't work on `"123","4"5""6","7"89"`

Comment: 1.
follow poster's meaning  
2.
usually only have the possibility in special column in a csv file
3.try
`echo '"123","4"5""6","7"89"'|sed -r ':a;s/(.*,"[^,]*)"([^"]*"(,|$))/\1\x27\2/;ta'`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following `awk` approach:

```
echo '"123","4"5""6","789"' | awk -F, '{OFS=","; $2="\""gensub(/\042/, "\047","g", substr($2, 2, length($2)-2))"\"";}1'
```

The output:

```
"123","4'5''6","789"
```

---

*Explanation:*

`-F,` (`OFS=","`) - treating `,` as field separator

`"\042"` - double quote ASCII octal code

`"\047"` - single quote ASCII octal code

`substr($2, 2, length($2)-2)` - extracting substring from the second field except trailing double quotes, i.e. `4"5""6`

`gensub(/\042/, "\047","g", [target])` - substitutes all double quotes with single quotes within the *target* string

Answer (score 0):

Another awk proposal:

```
echo '"123","4"5""6","789"' |awk '{sub(/4"5""/,"4\47"5"\47\47")}1'

"123","4'5''6","789"
```